# pymysql - python 3.6 on AWS Lambda - handling inserting data into SQL statements

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I have been spending hours trying to and searching for how to insert strings and decimals into a sql insert statement. I cannot seem to find an answer that works. I am using AWS Lambda with Python 3.6 to process data. I continue to have issues getting the values of variables to inserted into my SQL statement. I am getting the following error message.

My code:

```
timeStamp = 123456789.123456
thing = "Testing/IoT"
statement = "INSERT INTO `cycles` (`timeStamp`, `thing`) VALUES ({}, {})"
theData = (timeStamp, thing)
logger.info(statement, theData)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(statement, theData)
conn.commit()
```

Error message:

> not all arguments converted during string formatting: TypeError
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/var/task/recordCyclesRDS.py", line 56, in handler
>   logger.info(statement, theData) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1306, in info
>   self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1442, in _log
>   self.handle(record) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1452, in handle
>   self.callHandlers(record) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1514, in
>   callHandlers hdlr.handle(record) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 863, in handle
>   self.emit(record) File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line
>   442, in emit msg = self.format(record) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 838, in format
>   return fmt.format(record) File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 575, in format
>   record.message = record.getMessage() File
>   "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 338, in getMessage
>   msg = msg % self.args TypeError: not all arguments converted during
>   string formatting

I can make this work:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO `cycles` (`timeStamp`, `thing`) VALUES (123456.123456, 'Testing/IoT')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
timeStamp = 123456789.123456
thing = "Testing/IoT"
statement = "INSERT INTO `cycles` (`timeStamp`, `thing`) VALUES ({}, {})"
theData = (str(timeStamp), thing)
logger.info(statement, theData)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(statement, theData)
conn.commit()
```